# Select single row in table and post id to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on my first solo MVC project and I'm having some difficulty with a table in one of my views.  My table is nested inside a form that I'm hoping to use to post info to my controller and create a row in my database.

I want the user to be able to select a row from the table (either by clicking or use of a button present in each row) which will allow the id of the drug help in that row to be posted to the controller along with the rest of the data in the form.

**View**

```
@model DispensingApp.Models.ViewModels.NewScriptViewModel
@using PagedList;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Script</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Patient.FullName" class="control-label"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input readonly asp-for="Patient.FullName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-6 offset-2">
                @Html.TextBox("drugSearchString", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Drugs" class="control-label"></label>


            @if (Model.Drugs.Count() > 0)
            {

                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table-secondary">
                            <th></th>
                            <th>@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Create", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParam })</th>
                            <th>@Html.ActionLink("Pack Size", "Create", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.PackSizeSortParam })</th>
                            <th>@Html.ActionLink("Generic Ingredients", "Create", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.GenericSortParam })</th>
                            <th>@Html.ActionLink("Stock", "Create", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.StockSortParam })</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Drugs)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PackSize)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Generic.Name)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StockQty)</td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>No drugs available</p>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Qty" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Qty" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Qty" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Directions" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Directions" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Directions" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? id, string sortOrder, string drugSearchString)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            //sorting drugs table
            ViewBag.NameSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.PackSizeSortParam = sortOrder == "pack" ? "pack_desc" : "pack";
            ViewBag.GenericSortParam = sortOrder == "gen" ? "gen_desc" : "gen";
            ViewBag.StockSortParam = sortOrder == "stock" ? "stock_desc" : "stock";

            var drugs = await _context.Drug
                    .Include(d => d.Generic)
                    .ToListAsync();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(drugSearchString))
            {
                drugs = drugs.Where(d => d.Name.ToUpper().Contains(drugSearchString.ToUpper()) || d.Generic.Name.ToUpper().Contains(drugSearchString.ToUpper())).ToList();
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.Name).ToList();
                    break;
                case "pack_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.PackSize).ToList();
                    break;
                case "pack":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.PackSize).ToList();
                    break;
                case "gen_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.Generic.Name).ToList();
                    break;
                case "gen":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.Generic.Name).ToList();
                    break;
                case "stock_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.StockQty).ToList();
                    break;
                case "stock":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.StockQty).ToList();
                    break;
                default:
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.Name).ToList();
                    break;
            }



            var patient = await _context.Patient
                .Include(p => p.Title)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

            var prescribers = await _context.Prescriber
                .OrderBy(p => p.LastName)
                .ToListAsync();


            var vm = new NewScriptViewModel()
            {
                Patient = patient,
                Drugs = drugs,
                Prescribers = prescribers
            };

            ViewData["DrugId"] = new SelectList(_context.Drug, "Id", "Name");
            ViewData["PatientId"] = patient.Id;
            ViewData["PatientName"] = patient.FullName;
            ViewData["PrescriberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Prescriber, "Id", "FullName");
            ViewData["ShortCodeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ShortCode, "Id", "Directions");
            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Filter(int id, string drugSearchString)
        {
            var drugs = await _context.Drug
                .Include(d => d.Generic)
                .Where(d => d.Name.Contains(drugSearchString) || d.Generic.Name.Contains(drugSearchString))
                .ToListAsync();

            var patient = await _context.Patient.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

            var vm = new NewScriptViewModel()
            {
                Patient = patient,
                Drugs = drugs,
                Prescribers = await _context.Prescriber.ToListAsync()
            };
            return View("Create", vm);
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem that's occurring?

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not clear. Is the view correct - I see two submit buttons. Also, there is no html element which represents the "id" property that you are talking. Also, all the table data is display-only. So, not sure whether you can send table row back to controller or not. Also, when its display only, why do you want it to send back to controller? There are so many gaps